# Getting wrong type of objects in CDI Events

Tags: java, events, jboss, cdi

I am trying to count the amount of contextes created in my app (requests, sessions etc). For that I wrote a very simple class (System.out added for clarity and debug):

```
    public static void requestContextInitialized(@Observes @Initialized(RequestScoped.class) Object event){
    System.out.println("--- RequestScoped CREATED "+event+" "+event.getClass());
    requestStats.notifyInstanceCreated();
}

public static void requestContextDestroyed(@Observes @Destroyed(RequestScoped.class) Object event){
    System.out.println("--- RequestScoped DESTROYED "+event+" "+event.getClass());
    requestStats.notifyInstanceDestroyed();
}

public static void sessionContextInitialized(@Observes @Initialized(SessionScoped.class) Object event){
    System.out.println("--- SessionScoped CREATED "+event+" "+event.getClass());
    sessionStats.notifyInstanceCreated();
}

public static void sessionContextDestroyed(@Observes @Destroyed(SessionScoped.class) Object event){
    System.out.println("--- SessionScoped DESTROYED "+event+" "+event.getClass());
    sessionStats.notifyInstanceDestroyed();
}

public static void conversationContextInitialized(@Observes @Initialized(ConversationScoped.class) Object event){
    System.out.println("--- ConversationScoped CREATED");
    conversationStats.notifyInstanceCreated();
}

public static void conversationContextDestroyed(@Observes @Destroyed(ConversationScoped.class) Object event){
    System.out.println("--- ConversationScoped DESTROYED");
    conversationStats.notifyInstanceDestroyed();
}

public static void applicationContextInitialized(@Observes @Initialized(ApplicationScoped.class) Object event){
    System.out.println("--- ApplicationScoped CREATED");
    applicationStats.notifyInstanceCreated();
}

public static void applicationContextDestroyed(@Observes @Destroyed(ApplicationScoped.class) Object event){
    System.out.println("--- ApplicationScoped DESTROYED");
    applicationStats.notifyInstanceDestroyed();
}
```

According to CDI 1.1 Specification, for example here: http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.1.EDR1/html/contexts.html chapter 6.7.1 and so on, 
I should become Events with HttpServletRequest in my requestContextInitialized method. However, in all of my methods I permanently (on each request) getting events from Faces (I didn't asked for!):

21:48:48,643 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- RequestScoped CREATED javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent[source=com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl@673ae928] class javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent
21:48:48,643 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- SessionScoped DESTROYED javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent[source=com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl@673ae928] class javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent
21:48:48,644 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- ConversationScoped CREATED
21:48:48,645 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- SessionScoped CREATED javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent[source=com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl@673ae928] class javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent
21:48:48,646 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- ApplicationScoped DESTROYED
21:48:48,646 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- ApplicationScoped CREATED
21:48:48,647 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- ConversationScoped DESTROYED
21:48:48,647 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- RequestScoped DESTROYED javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent[source=com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl@673ae928] class javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent
21:48:48,667 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- RequestScoped CREATED javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent[source=com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl@673ae928] class javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent
21:48:48,668 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- SessionScoped DESTROYED javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent[source=com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl@673ae928] class javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent
21:48:48,669 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- ConversationScoped CREATED
21:48:48,669 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- SessionScoped CREATED javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent[source=com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl@673ae928] class javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent
21:48:48,670 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- ApplicationScoped DESTROYED
21:48:48,670 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- ApplicationScoped CREATED
21:48:48,671 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- ConversationScoped DESTROYED
21:48:48,672 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- RequestScoped DESTROYED javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent[source=com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl@673ae928] class javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent
21:48:48,673 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- RequestScoped CREATED javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent[source=com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl@673ae928] class javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent
21:48:48,674 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- SessionScoped DESTROYED javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent[source=com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl@673ae928] class javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent
21:48:48,675 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- ConversationScoped CREATED
21:48:48,675 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- SessionScoped CREATED javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent[source=com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl@673ae928] class javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent
21:48:48,676 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- ApplicationScoped DESTROYED
21:48:48,677 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- ApplicationScoped CREATED
21:48:48,677 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- ConversationScoped DESTROYED
21:48:48,678 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- RequestScoped DESTROYED javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent[source=com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl@673ae928] class javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent
21:48:48,693 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- RequestScoped CREATED javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent[source=com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl@673ae928] class javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent
21:48:48,700 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- SessionScoped DESTROYED javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent[source=com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl@673ae928] class javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent
21:48:48,701 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- ConversationScoped CREATED
21:48:48,702 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- SessionScoped CREATED javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent[source=com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl@673ae928] class javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent
21:48:48,702 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- ApplicationScoped DESTROYED
21:48:48,702 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- ApplicationScoped CREATED
21:48:48,703 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- ConversationScoped DESTROYED
21:48:48,704 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- RequestScoped DESTROYED javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent[source=com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl@673ae928] class javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent
21:48:48,706 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- RequestScoped CREATED javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent[source=com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl@673ae928] class javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent
21:48:48,707 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- SessionScoped DESTROYED javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent[source=com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl@673ae928] class javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent
21:48:48,707 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- ConversationScoped CREATED
21:48:48,708 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- SessionScoped CREATED javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent[source=com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl@673ae928] class javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent
21:48:48,709 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- ApplicationScoped DESTROYED
21:48:48,711 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- ApplicationScoped CREATED
21:48:48,712 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- ConversationScoped DESTROYED
21:48:48,712 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- RequestScoped DESTROYED javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent[source=com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl@673ae928] class javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent
21:48:48,718 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- RequestScoped CREATED javax.faces.event.PreValidateEvent[source=javax.faces.component.html.HtmlCommandButton@3d411fc6] class javax.faces.event.PreValidateEvent
21:48:48,719 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- SessionScoped DESTROYED javax.faces.event.PreValidateEvent[source=javax.faces.component.html.HtmlCommandButton@3d411fc6] class javax.faces.event.PreValidateEvent
21:48:48,720 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- ConversationScoped CREATED
21:48:48,720 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- SessionScoped CREATED javax.faces.event.PreValidateEvent[source=javax.faces.component.html.HtmlCommandButton@3d411fc6] class javax.faces.event.PreValidateEvent
21:48:48,721 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- ApplicationScoped DESTROYED
21:48:48,722 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- ApplicationScoped CREATED
21:48:48,722 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- ConversationScoped DESTROYED
21:48:48,722 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- RequestScoped DESTROYED javax.faces.event.PreValidateEvent[source=javax.faces.component.html.HtmlCommandButton@3d411fc6] class javax.faces.event.PreValidateEvent
21:48:48,724 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- RequestScoped CREATED javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent[source=com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl@673ae928] class javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent
21:48:48,725 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- SessionScoped DESTROYED javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent[source=com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl@673ae928] class javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent
21:48:48,731 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- ConversationScoped CREATED
21:48:48,731 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- SessionScoped CREATED javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent[source=com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl@673ae928] class javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent
21:48:48,732 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- ApplicationScoped DESTROYED
21:48:48,732 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- ApplicationScoped CREATED
21:48:48,733 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- ConversationScoped DESTROYED
21:48:48,733 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- RequestScoped DESTROYED javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent[source=com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl@673ae928] class javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent
21:48:48,735 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- RequestScoped CREATED javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent[source=com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl@673ae928] class javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent
21:48:48,738 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- SessionScoped DESTROYED javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent[source=com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl@673ae928] class javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent
21:48:48,739 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- ConversationScoped CREATED
21:48:48,739 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- SessionScoped CREATED javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent[source=com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl@673ae928] class javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent
21:48:48,742 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- ApplicationScoped DESTROYED
21:48:48,743 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- ApplicationScoped CREATED
21:48:48,744 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- ConversationScoped DESTROYED
21:48:48,745 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- RequestScoped DESTROYED javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent[source=com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl@673ae928] class javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent
21:48:48,748 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- RequestScoped CREATED javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent[source=com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl@673ae928] class javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent
21:48:48,748 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- SessionScoped DESTROYED javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent[source=com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl@673ae928] class javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent
21:48:48,749 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- ConversationScoped CREATED
21:48:48,749 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- SessionScoped CREATED javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent[source=com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl@673ae928] class javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent
21:48:48,750 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- ApplicationScoped DESTROYED
21:48:48,750 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- ApplicationScoped CREATED
21:48:48,751 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- ConversationScoped DESTROYED
21:48:48,751 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- RequestScoped DESTROYED javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent[source=com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl@673ae928] class javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent
21:48:48,754 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- RequestScoped CREATED javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent[source=com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl@673ae928] class javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent
21:48:48,755 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- SessionScoped DESTROYED javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent[source=com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl@673ae928] class javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent
21:48:48,757 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- ConversationScoped CREATED
21:48:48,760 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- SessionScoped CREATED javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent[source=com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl@673ae928] class javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent
21:48:48,763 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- ApplicationScoped DESTROYED
21:48:48,764 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- ApplicationScoped CREATED
21:48:48,765 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- ConversationScoped DESTROYED
21:48:48,765 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- RequestScoped DESTROYED javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent[source=com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl@673ae928] class javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent
21:48:48,794 INFO  [net.anotheria.moskito.core.registry.ProducerRegistryImpl] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) Registry register producer: NavigationController / OnDemandProducer (unlimited): NavigationController:default:web
21:48:48,800 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- RequestScoped CREATED org.jboss.seam.faces.event.PreNavigateEvent@4cb24f11 class org.jboss.seam.faces.event.PreNavigateEvent
21:48:48,802 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- SessionScoped DESTROYED org.jboss.seam.faces.event.PreNavigateEvent@4cb24f11 class org.jboss.seam.faces.event.PreNavigateEvent
21:48:48,802 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- ConversationScoped CREATED
21:48:48,803 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- SessionScoped CREATED org.jboss.seam.faces.event.PreNavigateEvent@4cb24f11 class org.jboss.seam.faces.event.PreNavigateEvent
21:48:48,805 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- ApplicationScoped DESTROYED
21:48:48,805 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- ApplicationScoped CREATED
21:48:48,805 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- ConversationScoped DESTROYED
21:48:48,807 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- RequestScoped DESTROYED org.jboss.seam.faces.event.PreNavigateEvent@4cb24f11 class org.jboss.seam.faces.event.PreNavigateEvent
21:48:48,810 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- RequestScoped CREATED javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent[source=com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl@673ae928] class javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent
21:48:48,811 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- SessionScoped DESTROYED javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent[source=com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl@673ae928] class javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent
21:48:48,812 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- ConversationScoped CREATED
21:48:48,813 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- SessionScoped CREATED javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent[source=com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl@673ae928] class javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent
21:48:48,814 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- ApplicationScoped DESTROYED
21:48:48,814 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- ApplicationScoped CREATED
21:48:48,814 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- ConversationScoped DESTROYED
21:48:48,815 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- RequestScoped DESTROYED javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent[source=com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl@673ae928] class javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent
21:48:48,816 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- RequestScoped CREATED javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent[source=com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl@673ae928] class javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent
21:48:48,817 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- SessionScoped DESTROYED javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent[source=com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl@673ae928] class javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent
21:48:48,818 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- ConversationScoped CREATED
21:48:48,819 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- SessionScoped CREATED javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent[source=com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl@673ae928] class javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent
21:48:48,820 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- ApplicationScoped DESTROYED
21:48:48,820 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- ApplicationScoped CREATED
21:48:48,820 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- ConversationScoped DESTROYED
21:48:48,821 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- RequestScoped DESTROYED javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent[source=com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl@673ae928] class javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent
21:48:48,880 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- RequestScoped CREATED javax.faces.event.PreRenderViewEvent[source=javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot@55280c0b] class javax.faces.event.PreRenderViewEvent
21:48:48,881 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- SessionScoped DESTROYED javax.faces.event.PreRenderViewEvent[source=javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot@55280c0b] class javax.faces.event.PreRenderViewEvent
21:48:48,882 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- ConversationScoped CREATED
21:48:48,882 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- SessionScoped CREATED javax.faces.event.PreRenderViewEvent[source=javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot@55280c0b] class javax.faces.event.PreRenderViewEvent
21:48:48,883 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- ApplicationScoped DESTROYED
21:48:48,883 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- ApplicationScoped CREATED
21:48:48,884 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- ConversationScoped DESTROYED
21:48:48,884 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- RequestScoped DESTROYED javax.faces.event.PreRenderViewEvent[source=javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot@55280c0b] class javax.faces.event.PreRenderViewEvent
21:48:48,892 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.renderkit] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) 'for' attribute cannot be null
21:48:48,900 INFO  [net.anotheria.moskito.core.registry.ProducerRegistryImpl] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) Registry register producer: RegistrationController / OnDemandProducer (unlimited): RegistrationController:default:web
21:48:49,438 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- RequestScoped CREATED javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent[source=com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl@673ae928] class javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent
21:48:49,439 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- SessionScoped DESTROYED javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent[source=com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl@673ae928] class javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent
21:48:49,440 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- ConversationScoped CREATED
21:48:49,440 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- SessionScoped CREATED javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent[source=com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl@673ae928] class javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent
21:48:49,441 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- ApplicationScoped DESTROYED
21:48:49,441 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- ApplicationScoped CREATED
21:48:49,442 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- ConversationScoped DESTROYED
21:48:49,442 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) --- RequestScoped DESTROYED javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent[source=com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl@673ae928] class javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent

I assume I am doing something wrong, but I don't understand what. 
The class in question is located under:
https://github.com/anotheria/moskito/blob/MSK-132/moskito-integration/moskito-cdi/java/net/anotheria/moskito/integration/cdi/scopes/ScopeInstanceCreationListener.java

and the whole application under:
https://github.com/dvayanu/moskito-jboss

JBoss AS7, Java7, MacOSX

Comment: JBoss AS7 uses Weld 1.1.x which is an implementation of CDI 1.0.  I don't believe this behavior is defined in CDI 1.0.  I am still curious to know how you're executing your tests.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for your reply. I am running this app: https://github.com/dvayanu/moskito-jboss

Comment: Mmmm it would probably help better if you were able to demonstrate with a standard test case.  You also sidestepped an important part of my statement, that you're actually running against CDI 1.0 not 1.1.